# How to fix long running compile time error Latex

Tags: compiling, overleaf, thesis

I am trying to write a paper in latex. The full code for the document is shown below:

```
% \documentclass[jou]{apa} %use "twoside for two-sided numbering

% %added by me
% \usepackage{subcaption}

% \usepackage{mathptmx}
% \usepackage{gsuthesisETD,multicol,amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,graphicx,geometry}
% %%%MY additions
% \usepackage{caption}
% %for bibliography
% \usepackage[english]{apacite}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage{csquotes, ellipsis}
% \MakeOuterQuote{"}
% \usepackage{xurl}
% \usepackage{listings}
% \usepackage{algorithm}
% \lstset{
% basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
% columns=flexible,
% breaklines=true
% }


% \geometry{letterpaper,left=1.3 true in, right=1.2 true in, top=1in, 
%           headheight =12pt, headsep =20pt, footskip =1in}
% \usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
% \usepackage{indentfirst}
% %Toggles: "true" or "false" 
% \tablespagetrue   
% \figurespagetrue 
% \symbolpagefalse  
% \dedicationpagetrue
% \acknowledgmentspagetrue
% \copyrightpagetrue
% \sectionnumberstrue

% % Fill in These Fields 
% \title{Design and Implementation of an Automatic Generator for Word-Matching Interactives}
% \author{Evan M. Gertis}
% \degree{Master of Science}
% \major{Computer Science}
% \dept{Department of Computer Science}
% \school{Georgia Southern University}
% \thesistype{Thesis}
% \graduatedate{May 2022}
% \graduateyear{2022}
% \keywords{Automatic Programming, Computer Science Education, Online learning, Programming Synthesis, Word Matching} 
% \cochair=0  %choose 1 if you have a co-chair
% \symbolfile{symbols} % symbols go in the file "symbols.tex"
% %\captiontype=1 %not used at this time
% \appendname{APPENDICES}  % or APPENDIX for just one
% \tocheader{Appendices}
% \mybibname{REFERENCES}
% \def\deansname{Dean's name} % Do NOT use "Dr." here.
% \committeechair{Dr. Daniel Liang} % No. Dr.
% \committeecochair{Co-advisor} % No Dr. 
% \memberC{Andrew Allen}
% \memberB{Ryan Florin}  
% \degreeA{B.S. Physics, University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill, 2017}


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MACROS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% %\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
% \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
% \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
% \newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
% \newtheorem{rmk}[theorem]{Remark}
% \newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
% \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
% \newtheorem{dfn}[theorem]{Definition}
% \newtheorem{ass}[theorem]{Assumption}
% \newcommand{\RR}{{\mathbb R}}
% \newcommand{\CC}{{\mathbb C}}
% \newcommand{\ZZ}{{\mathbb Z}}
% \newcommand{\NN}{{\mathbb N}}
% \newcommand{\rank}{{\rm rank}}

% \usepackage{dirtytalk}
% % \usepackage[options ]{algorithm2e}

% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Main Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% % \makeatletter
% % \def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
% %                       \if@mainmatter
% %                          \refstepcounter{chapter}%
% %                          \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
% %                          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
% %                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
% %                       \else
% %                          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
% %                       \fi
% %                     \chaptermark{#1}%
% % %                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% NEW
% % %                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% NEW
% %                     \if@twocolumn
% %                       \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
% %                     \else
% %                       \@makechapterhead{#2}%
% %                       \@afterheading
% %                     \fi}
% \begin{document}

% %  Version: \today  % Comment this out for final version

%   \input{abstract}
%   \titlep            
%   \copyrightpage  %optional (comment out if not used)
%   \approvalpage      
%   \input{dedication}  %optional
%   \input{acknowledgments} %optional
%   \tableofcontents 
%   \include{Chapter-1}
%   \include{Chapter-2}
%   \include{Chapter-3}
%   \include{Chapter-4}
%   \include{Chapter-5}
%   \include{Chapter-6}
%   \include{8-Bib}
  

%   \include{appendix}
  
% %\scriptsize

% %\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
% %\bibliography{refs}

% % \renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{myheadings}}
% % \printbibliography


% \end{document}


% OLD TEMPLATE PROVIDED BY GSU
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report} %use "twoside for two-sided numbering

%added by me
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{gsuthesisETD,multicol,amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,graphicx,geometry}
%%%MY additions
\usepackage{caption}
%for bibliography
\usepackage[english,backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes, ellipsis}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\lstset{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
columns=flexible,
breaklines=true
}


\geometry{letterpaper,left=1.3 true in, right=1.2 true in, top=1in, 
          headheight =12pt, headsep =20pt, footskip =1in}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%Toggles: "true" or "false" 
\figurespagetrue 
\symbolpagefalse  
\dedicationpagetrue
\acknowledgmentspagetrue
\copyrightpagetrue
\sectionnumberstrue

% Fill in These Fields 
\title{Design and Implementation of an Automatic Generator for Word Matching Interactives}
\author{Evan M. Gertis}
\degree{Master of Science}
\major{Computer Science}
\dept{Department of Computer Science}
\school{Georgia Southern University}
\thesistype{Thesis}
\graduatedate{May 2022}
\graduateyear{2022}
\keywords{Automatic programming, Computer science education, Online learning, programming synthesis, Word matching} 
\cochair=0  %choose 1 if you have a co-chair
\symbolfile{symbols} % symbols go in the file "symbols.tex"
%\captiontype=1 %not used at this time
\appendname{APPENDICES}  % or APPENDIX for just one
\tocheader{Appendices}
\mybibname{REFERENCES}
\def\deansname{Dean's name} % Do NOT use "Dr." here.
\committeechair{Daniel Liang} % No. Dr.
\committeecochair{Co-advisor} % No Dr. 
\memberC{Andrew Allen}
\memberB{Ryan Florin}  
\degreeA{B.S., University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill, 2017}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MACROS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{rmk}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{dfn}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{ass}[theorem]{Assumption}
\newcommand{\RR}{{\mathbb R}}
\newcommand{\CC}{{\mathbb C}}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{{\mathbb Z}}
\newcommand{\NN}{{\mathbb N}}
\newcommand{\rank}{{\rm rank}}

\usepackage{dirtytalk}
% \usepackage[options ]{algorithm2e}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Main Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \makeatletter
% \def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
%                       \if@mainmatter
%                          \refstepcounter{chapter}%
%                          \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
%                          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
%                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
%                       \else
%                          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
%                       \fi
%                     \chaptermark{#1}%
% %                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% NEW
% %                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% NEW
%                     \if@twocolumn
%                       \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
%                     \else
%                       \@makechapterhead{#2}%
%                       \@afterheading
%                     \fi}
\begin{document}

%  Version: \today  % Comment this out for final version

  \input{abstract}
  \titlep            
  \copyrightpage  %optional (comment out if not used)
  \approvalpage      
  \input{dedication}  %optional
  \input{acknowledgments} %optional
  \tableofcontents 
  \include{Chapter-1}
  \include{Chapter-2}
  \include{Chapter-3}
  \include{Chapter-4}
  \include{Chapter-5}
  \include{Chapter-6}
  \include{8-Bib}
  

  \include{appendix}
  
%\scriptsize

%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
%\bibliography{refs}

% \renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{myheadings}}
% \printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Expected:
The document should compile and produce the pdf required.

Actual:
[image]

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. It is the first time that I've encountered this error.

Recent update
[image]

Latex support doesn't even know what to do here.'

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is anything we can say with the information provided. TeX itself has no time limits, overleaf does impose some (and increases them for paid accounts)  but the time is taken up by the document files you have not shown. not the preamble. Perhaps you have large tikz pictures that just take too long, or perhaps you have a tex error and an infinite loop, impossible to say.

Comment: Do you have lots of TikZ?  That can cause a long compilation.  Is there a particular chapter that is causing the timeout?  That would suggest that you have an error in that chapter.

Comment: I need to compile these documents within the next 4 hours. Do you know of a different compiler?

Comment: if you have a fatal error in your code that leads to a loop another compiler won't help you. Comment all \include lines and try if it compiles. If yes add one file after another until you find the problematic one.

Comment: The error message includes a link to a help page which recommends adding a latexmkrc file to your project that will instruct the compiler to halt on error, rather than trying to continue. This may help you identify the source of any fatal errors. If you have trouble understanding the errors you encounter with this or have trouble following the instructions on that page, please reach out to Overleaf support (support@overleaf.com).

Comment: I contacted support

Comment: Look, we cannot debug without a MWE (see [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means).

Comment: Not sure about overleaf support but I don't think they're responsible for debugging users' bugs either, they help with issues with the platform.

Comment: There are certain things that are more efficient than "binary search debugging" but you need somewhat-advanced knowledge of TeX to use.

Comment: If I use what you've posted, and comment out the files I don't have, and comment out the commands that are defined in the files I don't have, then what you've posted compiles on Overleaf in 2 seconds.  Put `\includeonly{nochapters}` just before `\begin{document}`, and see if you can get it to compile.  Then follow our advice and narrow done the problem to what's causing the issue.

Comment: This question teaches how to not ask a question and why sources must be organized in order to find/spot errors and mistakes as soon as possible. The presented document might have been compiled with errors for a long time without user noticing it.

Answer (score 3):

This was too long for a comment.

From [Overleaf website](https://it.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Why_do_I_keep_getting_the_compile_timeout_error_message%3F)

> Unfortunately, some LaTeX compile errors can block the latexmk build
> process completely and therefore lead to a timeout. In order to debug
> such errors **it may be necessary to add a file named `latexmkrc` (without
> any file extension) to your project, on the top level, containing just
> these three lines:**
>
> ```bash
> $pdflatex = 'pdflatex --halt-on-error %O %S';
> $lualatex = 'lualatex --halt-on-error %O %S';
> $xelatex = 'xelatex --halt-on-error %O %S';
> ```
>
> This would then make the compilation halt at the very first compile
> error message that occurs (albeit without generating any output
> preview). You can then debug and correct each error you come across
> until the project is error-free; you can then delete this latexmkrc.
> (If you still get a timeout even with this latexmkrc file, it is
> likely that the main cause is one of the issues discussed in previous
> sections.)

After having done this, maybe you should comment out the chapters one by one and try to compile every chapter singularly to spot the error, for example like so:

```latex
\begin{document}

%  Version: \today  % Comment this out for final version

%  \input{abstract}
%  \titlep            
%  \copyrightpage  %optional (comment out if not used)
%  \approvalpage      
%  \input{dedication}  %optional
%  \input{acknowledgments} %optional
%  \tableofcontents 
  \include{Chapter-1}
%  \include{Chapter-2}
%  \include{Chapter-3}
%  \include{Chapter-4}
%  \include{Chapter-5}
%  \include{Chapter-6}
%  \include{8-Bib}
  

%  \include{appendix}

\end{document}
```

Try doing this for every bit of yout document, i.e. chapters, biblio, appendix, abstract, dedication, acknowledgements, titlepage, copyrightpage, approvalpage, etc...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Or `\includeonly{Chapter-1}`.

Comment: that did not work.

Answer (score 3):

OP narrowed the problem down to the line:

```tex
%for bibliography
\usepackage[english,backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{babel}
```

This appears to be mixing options for babel and biblatex (or possibly apacite), so that it should have been

```tex
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

While LaTeX allows you to combine multiple packages into one `\usepackage` command, you should rarely do so (perhaps the AMS packages).  I would place related `\usepackage` commands near each other in the source instead.  This keeps you from passing options to packages that aren't expecting them, and prevents you from deleting a package that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. My problems stemmed from the usage of the biber package.

```
%for bibliography
\usepackage[english,backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{babel}
```

I had to completely remove this package and implement APA citations by hand.

Comment: I'm not sure if `style=apa` is a option for `babel`. I know this sintaxe: `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Now that you've narrowed it down: it really looks like `\usepackage[english,backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{babel}` should be `\usepackage[english]{babel}\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{biblatex}`.